# Liquibase Rollback in Java Doesn't Seem To Be Working

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing, liquibase

I am using Liquibase as part of my integration tests in Java. During the integration-test phase, I use Liquibase to create and populate my tables in the @BeforeClass function. My changesets are tagged once they are applied. In the @After function, I run a rollback to a specific tag.

I am then able to run unit tests to SELECT from the database as well as INSERT. However, I then try to rollback the changes after each test and am finding that Liquibase is not rolling back my changes.

I am using Liquibase 3.1.1 against an embedded Derby database.

My changeset file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

<include file="create-table-event-type.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
<include file="load-table-event-type.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

<include file="create-table-event.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
<include file="load-table-event.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

<changeSet id="tag-integration-test-database" author="Ivan Suftin" context="integration-test">
    <tagDatabase tag="integration-tests-tag" />
</changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

My unit test:

```java
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public class EventDAOTest {

private static Connection conn;
private static SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;
private static Liquibase liquibase;
private EventDAO instance = null;
private static final String rollbackTag = "integration-tests-tag";
private static final Contexts contexts = new Contexts("integration-test");

public EventDAOTest() {
}

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, DatabaseException, LiquibaseException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
    String port = System.getProperty("db.twitter.integration-test.port");
    String driver = System.getProperty("db.twitter.integration-test.driver");
    String dbType = System.getProperty("db.twitter.integration-test.dbtype");
    String schema = System.getProperty("db.twitter.integration-test.schema");
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(port)) {
        throw new NullPointerException("System property \"db.twitter.integration-test.port\" not found");
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(driver)) {
        throw new NullPointerException("System property \"db.twitter.integration-test.driver\" not found");
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(dbType)) {
        throw new NullPointerException("System property \"db.twitter.integration-test.dbType\" not found");
    }
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(schema)) {
        throw new NullPointerException("System property \"db.twitter.integration-test.schema\" not found");
    }

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + dbType + "://localhost:" + port + "/" + schema + ";create=true", "test", "test");

    Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(conn));
    liquibase = new Liquibase("src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml", new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), database);

    liquibase.update(contexts);

    try (InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream("mybatis-config.xml")) {
        sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream, "integration-test");
    }
}


@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() throws SQLException {
    conn.close();
}

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    instance = new EventDAO(sqlSessionFactory);
}

@After
public void afterTest() throws DatabaseException, LiquibaseException {
    liquibase.rollback(rollbackTag, contexts);
}
```

[...]

The rest of the test is just me using MyBatis to SELECT and INSERT.

Here's what the logs look like (just pasting the important parts)

```
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: Creating database history table with name: TEST.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: Reading from TEST.DATABASECHANGELOG
```

[ ... runs the changesets ... ]

```
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml: tag-integration-test-database::Ivan Suftin: Reading from TEST.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml: tag-integration-test-database::Ivan Suftin: Tag 'integration-tests-tag' applied to database
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml: tag-integration-test-database::Ivan Suftin: ChangeSet src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml::tag-integration-test-database::Ivan Suftin ran successfully in 11ms
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml: tag-integration-test-database::Ivan Suftin: Reading from TEST.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

Between each test, I try to run a rollback so I get a freshly loaded database to play with and the logs are shown here:

```
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: Reading from TEST.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: Reading from TEST.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 3/8/14 7:23 PM:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
-- *********************************************************************
-- Rollback to 'integration-tests-tag' Script
-- *********************************************************************
-- Change Log: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml
-- Ran at: 3/8/14 7:23 PM
-- Against: test@jdbc:derby://localhost:59527/twitter;create=true
-- Liquibase version: 3.1.1
-- *********************************************************************

-- Lock Database
-- Rolling Back ChangeSet: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml::tag-integration-test-database::Ivan Suftin
DELETE FROM TEST.DATABASECHANGELOG  WHERE ID='tag-integration-test-database' AND AUTHOR='Ivan Suftin' AND FILENAME='src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/create-table-parent-changeLog.xml';

-- Release Database Lock
```

The table I test against initially has two rows. I have two tests that do an insert. They run one after the other. In the first test, I run an INSERT for one row and then immediately run a SELECT to count the amount of rows. The result shows 3 rows, which is correct.

The next test also runs an INSERT for one row and again I run a SELECT to test the row count and it should be 3 rows but now I get 4 rows. This tells me that the rollback in the @After function is effectively doing nothing.

Is it me doing something wrong here?

I've also tried using the Java API to do create a tag immediately after the changelogs are run by running:

```java
liquibase.tag(rollbackTag);
```

... but I get the same result. Nothing gets rolled back.

Answer (score 7):

Liquibase doesn't automatically generate rollback commands for insert statements, so unless you put those in manually Liquibase won't do anything. See http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html for the docs on that.

> Many refactorings such as “create table”, “rename column”, and “add
>   column” can automatically create rollback statements. If your change
>   log contains only statements that fit into this category, your
>   rollback commands will be generated automatically.
>
> Other refactorings such as “drop table” and “insert data” have no
>   corresponding rollback commands that can be automatically generated.
>   In these cases, and cases where you want to override the default
>   generated rollback commands, you can specify the rollback commands via
>   the tag within the changeSet tag. If you do not want anything done to
>   undo a change in rollback mode, use an empty tag.

Comment: If you dig deeper into the documentation at http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/insert.html, it will show for each command and each database, whether autorollback works. For example, the insert command http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/insert.html does not support autorollback for any database.